# CodeIgniter Datatable Date Search Range

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need to find data from a certain date range. Please help me

Model

```
public function Date($start_date, $end_date){

$query = $this->db->select($this->tables['table_search'])
    ->where($this->tables['table_search'].'.created_at >=', $start_date)
    ->where($this->tables['table_search'].'.created_at <=', $end_date)
    ->group_by($this->tables['table_search'].".created_at")
    ->get($this->tables['table_search']);

return $query->result_array();
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function Date()
    {
        $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
        $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

        $return = $this->m_model->Date($start_date,$end_date);

        echo json_encode($return);
    }
```

Ajax J'S

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
todayBtn: 'linked',           
format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
autoclose: true
});
```

function fetch_data(start_date='', end_date=''){
            var dataTable = $('#table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order":[],
            "ajax":{
            url: "search/Date",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
            start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
            },
            success:function(data){
            $('#table').html(data);
            }
            }
            });
            }

```
        $('#search').click(function(){

        var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
        var end_date = $('#end_date').val();

        if(start_date != '' && end_date != ''){
        $('#table').DataTable().destroy();
        fetch_data(start_date,end_date);
        }else{
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server side processing you have to return proper JSON format from controller, see [Datatables serverside docs](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html).

Here for the client side :

```
$('#table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "search/Date",
            "type": "POST"
            "data": function ( d ) {
                var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
                var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
                if(start_date != '' && end_date != ''){
                  d.start_date = start_date;
                  d.end_date = end_date;
                }
            }
        }
    } );
```

Some parameter send automatically on ajax request like start and length for paging, see [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) to limit the query result.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: is your table server side by default(before search range) or not ? if i see your pieces of code it is not because you are re-initializing the table after get the result, so if it is not serverside, you will only need make a function to get the new filtered html table content from server and re-initializing the DataTable. See here https://gist.github.com/bagus-repository/37e64c1d1d9837bcf7a74e9f25b56291